# Implement React Native compatible location tracking native module from swift

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, react-native, geolocation

Im trying to implement location tracking module to react native from swift which uses Significant Location Tracking.
Currently I have implemented the react native bridge which transfer data from native ios modules. Also converted the appDelegate file to swift from objective-c

The Issue that I'm currently having is this module works fine in app foreground and background states, but after **terminating the app** no location hits get generated from the native side anymore.

Is there a way to wake up the react native app from the native side when app has been terminated, so that it continues to fetch the location or is there any issue with my current implementation?

My current implementation look like this,

**React native Bridge**

```
#import "React/RCTEventEmitter.h"
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTEventDispatcher.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import <React/RCTUtils.h>
#import <React/RCTConvert.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
```

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

@available(iOS 14.0, *)
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
var window: UIWindow?
var bridge: RCTBridge!

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions 
launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
let jsCodeLocation: URL
UIDevice.current.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true

jsCodeLocation = 
RCTBundleURLProvider.sharedSettings().jsBundleURL(forBundleRoot:"index")
let rootView = RCTRootView(bundleURL: jsCodeLocation, moduleName: "AppName", 
initialProperties: nil, launchOptions: launchOptions)
let rootViewController = UIViewController()
rootViewController.view = rootView

self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
self.window?.rootViewController = rootViewController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

Datastore.shared.appLastLaunchedDate = Date()
Datastore.shared.loadData()
UserDefaults.standard.register( defaults: ["trackingMethod": "significantLocation"])

let authStatus = LocationManager.shared.clLocationManager.authorizationStatus
if authStatus == .authorizedWhenInUse || authStatus == .authorizedAlways {
    LocationManager.shared.clLocationManager.delegate = self
    LocationManager.shared.startMonitoring()
}



return true
```

}
}

**GetLocation.m**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
#import "React/RCTEventEmitter.h"

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(getLocation, RCTEventEmitter)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(startSignificantTracking)

@end
```

**GetLocation.swift**

```
@objc(getLocation)
class getLocation: RCTEventEmitter, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
  ....
  @objc
  func startSignificantTracking() {
  locationManager?.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
  }

  @objc
  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, 
  didUpdateLocations clLocations: 
  [CLLocation]) {

  let generator = UINotificationFeedbackGenerator()
  generator.notificationOccurred(.success)

        let location = Location(clLocation: clLocation)
        let locatioObj: [String: Any] = [
          "latitude": location.clLocation.coordinate.latitude,
          "longitude": location.clLocation.coordinate.longitude,
        ]
      sendEvent(withName: "LocationUpdate", body: 
      ["Data":locatioObj])
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the existing solution https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service#watchpositionsuccesscallback-errorcallback-options

Btw you can check how it is implemented in this library.